# FastAPI route works in Swagger but returns HTTP 422 in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, http, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app that implements a route like so.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

api = FastAPI()

@api.post("/myroute/")
def myroute(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    return f"a={a}, b={b}"
```

This works as expected when I run the server and use Swagger to interact with it.

I have the following unit test.

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

def test_myroute():
    client = TestClient(api)
    response = client.post("/myroute/", json={"a": "dog", "b": "cat"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

The unit test fails with an [HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422).

Have I written the unit test incorrectly?

There is a similar StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854588/test-with-fastapi-testclient-returns-422-status-code), but there the solution is to use the `json` keyword in the unit test, which I am already doing.

Comment: Your route is asking for the URL `/myroute/?a=foo&b=bar` - not a JSON body (a JSON body would imply that you had a Pydantic model, not two plain strings). You can see which request is actually made when you invoke the endpoint through swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

api = FastAPI()

class Arguments(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str

@api.post("/myroute/")
def myroute(arguments: Arguments) -> str:
    return f"a={arguments.a}, b={arguments.b}":
```

See the comment responding to the original post for an explanation.